# How can I password-protect pages in sveltekit?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to figure out the best way to password-protect some pages in Svelte. This is for a game, so I'm not exactly trying to keep the NSA out. I'm just trying to keep a reasonably-determined user from cheating.

Ideally the user would not be able to:

1. See the password (duh)
2. See that the routes exist by examining the source
3. Download any of the JavaScript associated with those pages

What's the simplest way of doing this? I'm guessing I'd have to do some password-checking server-side. Is there a way I can do that that's compatible with netlify/vercel?

Comment: This question is a bit too broad, as SO is generally for specific problem solving. That aside, you only need one constant password to access the page, right? Like each user wouldn't have their own password. In that case, you could simply redirect a user to a login page if they're not signed in, and when they are, store a JWT cookie.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how I could make this more specific. I mean sure, that's a good general approach I could take. But I'm trying to figure out what tools Svelte/sveltekit give me to do this. It's a spare-time project, so I don't have a ton of time to set up a whole backend infrastructure or anything.

Comment: I may have made it sound more complicated than it really is. Take ~10 minutes to find out how JWT works, then take another 10 minutes to implement it in your app. Then you're done.